# Value updated like pointers: I don't get it

Tags: python, numpy

I always believed that, in python, the syntax `a=b` applied the value of `b` to `a`.
Although, in the example below, the value of image_init seems to be updated, what am I missing here??

```
import numpy as np
img = np.zeros((3,3))
img_init = img
img[-1,:]=[1]
print img
print
print img_init
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

EDIT: Let me correct a bit the question. First, both img and img_init are numpy array, not list. Then, I'm not looking for a way to copy the list, I'm just looking for the reason why img_init gets updated,
Thanks already for all the answers!

Comment: Use `img_init = copy.deepcopy(img)`

Comment: No; all names in Python reference objects; `a=b` makes the name `a` reference the same object as the name `b`.

Comment: That indeed seems a possibility, but I was more looking at the reason why the value of image_init get updated, while, in my point of view, it shouldn't... isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy array assignment problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059395/numpy-array-assignment-problem)

Comment: that can't be chepner, try a=1
b=a
a=2

print a
print b

Comment: @Arno Integers are immutable.

Comment: Moreover, `a = [1]` `b = a` `a = [2]` will still behave the same as your example.  *Reassigning* `a` after making `b` a reference to the same object as `a` has no effect on `b`.  It's only changing *properties* of the object pointed to that seems confusing.  Integers don't have properties.

Comment: Consider reading http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I don't agree that this question is a duplicate as marked, and I think the highest-voted answers to the linked question miss the real meat of the question here, which is "Why does my variable behave like a pointer?"  OP doesn't care *how* to copy the list (or object or whatever), he wants to know *why he has to*.