# Variable not changing after assigning another value to its dependent variable

Tags: python, variables

Entering the following code into Python 3.5 shell gives me an answer I didn't expect, very basic I know but would somebody help me with an explanation please.

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 2
>>> a = x*y
>>> x,y,a
(5, 2, 10)

>>> x = 3
>>> x,y,a
(3, 2, 10)
```

These were all on separate lines each preceded by >>>

I expected 6, but the "new" x has not been used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python assigning multiple variables to same value? list behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348815/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-value-list-behavior)

Comment: Or [python variables are pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13530998/2301450). Or [Why variable = object doesn't work like variable = number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29926485/2301450).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are python variables pointers? or else what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they)

Answer (score 2):

`a = x*y` isn't an equation that automatically updates `a` whenever you change `x` or `y`. It sets `a` to `x*y` *once* when the statement is run. Any changes to `x` or `y` afterward have no effect on `a`.

You'll need to manually update `a` when you change `x` or `y`, or, if the situation allows it, use local functions to do what @Silvio's answer shows. It's handy to create local shortcuts to help clean up code.

Answer (score 2):

The 'a' variable will only be updated if you update it deliberately. 
In order to update 'a' after you have changed 'x', you will need to execute the line a = x*y again.

If you copy and paste your code into here http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit it will give you a good visualization of what is going on!

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `a`, the value is set then and there.

```
a = x * y
```

The *current* values of `x` and `y` are used. The expression `x * y` isn't stored anywhere, so Python can't possibly know to update it. If you want a value that automatically updates based on the values of its variables, you can use a closure.

```
x = 5
y = 2
a = lambda: x * y
print(x, y, a()) # Prints 5 2 10
x = 3
print(x, y, a()) # Prints 3 2 6
```

This ensures that the expression is evaluated every time `a` is called.

Answer (score 0):

`a` variable won't be updated. You may want to create a function this way

```
def a(x,y):
    return x*y
```

And then you can create the tuple

```
(x, y, a(x,y))
```

Comment: So where's the explanation the OP asked for?