# Why does it show the same value after changing a variable?

Tags: python

I write this code:

```
a=5
b=4
s=a*b
print(s)
20
```

then I changed variable "a" to 6:

```
a=6
print(s)
20
```

I changed variable "a" and when i say `print(a)` it shows new variable(6) but when I say `print(s)` it shows the same number(20) 
I wonder why this happens. I expected it shows me s=24 but why it shows 20 again?

Comment: Because `s` is  `20`. It doesn't  _magically_ change.

Comment: why should it show something different? If you change your address, do all your bills magically appear at your new address?

Comment: because we changed "a" and "s" value is depend on the value of "a"

Comment: It is not at all "dependent" on the value of `a`. Its value is calculated by it, **once**, and that's it. The first line of `s` is equivalent to `s = 5 * 4`. It is not aware that this value came from `a` and doesn't care if it changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable not changing (Python 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374966/variable-not-changing-python-3-5). Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they

Comment: thank you guys I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very reasonable question to ask. The reason it does not change is that `s` gets the *result* of the calculation `a*b`, and does not represent the actual function `a*b`. This is just how python works and can be different from other languages.

You *can* achieve something similar to what you want by using a lambda:

```
a=5
b=4
s=lambda: a*b
print(s()) # prints 20
a=6
print(s()) # prints 24
```

note that you will have to call the lamdba using `s()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate s again to change s.

```py
a=6
s=a*b
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you changed `a=6` you have to compute `s=a*b` again to take in account the new value of `a`.