# Why is a variable not updating after changing its dependent variable?

Tags: python, variables, debugging

I don't understand why the variable 'y' doesn't update when I change the x? (The 'y' variable is dependent on 'x' right?)

```
x = 5
y = x*2

print(x)
print(y)

x = 3

# Expect it to print '3' and '6' instead it print '3' and '10'
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: _The 'y' variable is dependent on 'x' right?_ No, `y` is created based on the `x` value, but after that they're only friends.

Comment: immutable objects like `int`, `float`, `string` are saved by value not by reference. So, when you change `x`, the value of  unlike mutable objects

Comment: in your first declaration you can think of it as simple `y = 5*2` instead of `y=x*2`. After the initial declaration they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: See also: [Variable not changing after assigning another value to its dependent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46374966/7851470)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (The 'y' variable is dependent on 'x' right?

No.

Few programming languages have dependent / computed *variables*<sup>[0]</sup> and Python is *not* one of them<sup>[1]</sup>. When `y = x*2` is executed, the expression on the right-side of the `=` is fully evaluated and the result set as the value of `y`. `y` is thereafter independent from `x`<sup>[2]</sup>.

Generally speaking, if you want `y` to be a function of `x`... you define it as a function of `x`:

```py
x = 5
def y(): return x*2

print(x)
print(y())

x = 3

# Expect it to print '3' and '6' instead it print '3' and '10'
print(x)
print(y())
```

---

0. I know of `make`'s lazy variables and Perl's tied scalars
1. it does have computed *attributes* (aka properties) but that's a very different thing
2. There are situations which kind-of look like dependent variables e.g. if you set `y` to a mutable sub-structure of `x` changes to this sub-part of `x` will be visible through `y`. That's not actually a dependency though, it's just that the two variables point to the same (mutable) structure, so both "see" mutations applied to that shared structure.

Comment: Just to elaborate on footnote [2]. An example of this is when you have a list such as ```x = [1, 2, 3]```. Setting ```y = x``` causes both variables to point to the same mutable structure. So if you do something like ```x[0] = 10``` followed by ```print(y[0])```, you will get an output of 10, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

*The `y` variable is dependent on `x` right?*

Well, first things first, if you set:

```
a = 7
b = a
a = 4
```

Then,

`print(id(a))` and `print(id(b))`, you will get two different ids, hence `b` will not change when you overwrite `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your y points to an older version of the x-variable.
To update y, you could do:

```
x = 5
y = x * 2

print(x)
print(y)

x = 3
y = x * 2

print(x)
print(y)
```

Which will output:

```
5
10
3
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Because after you assign a value to variable `y`, in order to change it you will need to access directly to `y`.
`y= x*2` is assigning value to `y` according to what the value of `x` in this line of code. this how python works, there are other code languages who can preform like u expected. 
after assigning the new value to `x` , you will need to write again `y=x*2`.