# Is it possible to let the value of a python variable change dynamically?

Tags: python

For example, take the code

```
import numpy as np

np_function = np.add
np.__dict__.update({"add": 10})
print(np.add, np_function)
```

`np.add` gives 10, but `np_function` still points to the original numpy function, since it was assigned before the update of the dictionary. Is there any way for us to update the value of `np_function` if the value of `np.add` changes?

Comment: TL;DR: no. Variables hold references to objects. They have absolutely no way of knowing when a different variable gets bound to a different object. `np_function` will keep referencing the object that was assigned to it until you explicitly bind it to a different object.

Comment: @Brian add as an answer. This should be really useful for others in the future.

Comment: @BlueRobin I'm almost certain this question is a duplicate. If I can't find a good dupe target, then I'll make that an answer

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: [Why is a variable not updating after changing its dependent variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62042913/11082165), [Are Python variables pointers? Or else, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13530998/11082165), [If two variables point to the same object, why doesn't reassigning one variable affect the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56667280/11082165)

Comment: Technically this is possible, but you really shouldn't do this and it probably wouldn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what exactly you need. This can range from "simple" to "difficult" up to "impossible" depending on the fine print. Do you want *all* variables to change when their referent is updated or only specific ones? Do you want this only for specific referents or all of them? Do you want this for module globals or also other kinds of variables (e.g. function locals, class locals, attributes, ...)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'd like it for all referents ideally. I'd say class attributes would be the most common for me if you have a simple solution for that case

Comment: @matt For a class (instances, actually) I'd go directly with properties so that the lookup is performed anew on every access. No need to actually have and update real attributes.