# Problems with shuffling arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having this unusual problem with shuffling arrays in numpy

```
arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
print "Original constant array"
print arr
new_arr=arr
for i in range(3):        
    np.random.shuffle(new_arr)
    print "Obtained constant array"
    print arr
    print "randomized array"
    print new_arr
```

`arr` is my original array which I kept as such and created new array `new_arr` for further computation. But the code is showing this output

```
Original constant array
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
Obtained constant array
[[6 7 8]
 [0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
randomized array
[[6 7 8]
 [0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
```

I only wants to randomize `new_arr` and not `arr`. why this is happening and how to prevent `arr` from shuffling?

Comment: "created new array `new_arr`" - no you didn't. `new_arr=arr` doesn't make a new array. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html (but slicing works a bit differently between lists and NumPy arrays, so don't try to apply the parts about slicing to NumPy arrays).

Comment: You probably need to create a deep copy. See [numpy array assignment problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059395/numpy-array-assignment-problem) for the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
new_arr = np.copy(arr)
```

instead of

```
new_arr = arr
```

When you do `new_arr=arr` you basically create a reference `new_arr` for your array `arr`

---

for example (Taken from [numpy copy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)):

```
Create an array x, with a reference y and a copy z:
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> y = x
>>> z = np.copy(x)

Note that, when we modify x, y changes, but not z:
>>> x[0] = 10
>>> x[0] == y[0]
True
>>> x[0] == z[0]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `new_arr=arr`, it copies the reference--it does not do a deep copy. Then when you change arr, it changes new_arr too.

Try `new_arr = np.copy(arr)`. That should work.